# Model not binding in MVC

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, binding, model-binding

I have this issue every now & then and I never know how to properly and easily fix it. So please help me once and for all!

My `form`(cihForm) is not binding to the view. Once i load the view, add text to the two input boxes, and click my 'save' button the debugger goes to my "New" constructor in the `FormsViewModel` > Populates the Clubs and Categories as it should, once it is finished there the debugger goes to my `Create_Post` function in the 'controller'.

Once it is inside the `HTTPpost` action my model has clubs and categories as it should, but the form is empty. All of my fields have 'nothing' or default data assigned to it.

**Model**

```
Public Class FormsViewModel
    Public form As cihForm = New cihForm()
    Public Clubs As List(Of cihOrganizationSub) = New List(Of cihOrganizationSub)
    Public Categories As List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef) = New List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef)

    Public Sub New()
        Dim lists As cihLists = New cihLists()

        'Clubs
        lists.loadOrganizationSubs(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, ZenCommon.CurrentUserId)
        Clubs = New cihOrganizationSubList(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, ZenCommon.CurrentUserId).subList

        'Categories
        lists.loadCategoryOrgDef(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId)
        Categories = lists.organizationClubCategories

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Controller**

```
<HttpGet>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Get() As ActionResult
    Dim viewModel As FormsViewModel = New FormsViewModel()
    Dim emptyList() As String = {}

    'List of Orgs
    ViewBag.SubOrgList = New SelectList(viewModel.Clubs, "subId", "codDescr", viewModel.form.selectedSubOrgId)

    'List of Events
    Dim search As cihEventSearch = New cihEventSearch(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, "", Date.Now.AddMonths(-1), Date.Now.AddMonths(1), True, emptyList, emptyList, emptyList)
    ViewBag.EventList = New SelectList(search.eventList.OrderByDescending(Function(evt) evt.startUtc), "eventId", "eventTitle", viewModel.form.selectedEventId)

    ViewBag.HideRightColumn = True
    ViewBag.BodyClass = "span10"

    Return View()
End Function

<HttpPost>
<ActionName("Create")>
Function Create_Post(form As FormsViewModel) As ActionResult

    Return View()
End Function
```

**View**

```
    @ModelType MVCProject.FormsViewModel
    @Using Html.BeginForm()
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.form.Title, New With {.placeholder = "Title", .class = "hideOffFocus input-full large-type"})
        @Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) model.form.Description, New With {.placeholder = "Description", .class = "hideOffFocus input-full"})

<input type="submit" name="cmdSave" value="Save" id="cmdSave" class="btn btn-primary" />
    End Using
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was that i forgot to label my items with the  "Property" tag inside my Model. I hate that i have to do this for VB.

```
Public Class FormsViewModel
    Public Property form As cihForm = New cihForm()
    Public Property Clubs As List(Of cihOrganizationSub) = New List(Of cihOrganizationSub)
    Public Property Categories As List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef) = New List(Of cihCategoryOrgDef)

    Public Sub New()
        Dim lists As cihLists = New cihLists()

        'Clubs
        lists.loadOrganizationSubs(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, ZenCommon.CurrentUserId)
        Clubs = New cihOrganizationSubList(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId, ZenCommon.CurrentUserId).subList

        'Categories
        lists.loadCategoryOrgDef(ZenCommon.CurrentOrgId)
        Categories = lists.organizationClubCategories

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind the model using `@Model MVCProject.FormsViewModel` in your **View**.

Comment: My view is using VB as the main language. VB uses @ModelType , but thanks anyways